# Advanced CSS Circles

Tags: layout, css

I'm trying to make 3 different circles to my website. I don't want to insert it as a graphic/image file. So I've been trying to achieve it using CSS3, but I can't really work my fingers around it.

**What will it look like?**
I have uploaded a picture of what I'm trying to achieve at: [www.sp34k.com/etc/circles.jpg](http://www.sp34k.com/etc/circles.jpg)
I can't really show the code I've been trying to use to achieve this, as it all looks totally weird and nothing floats currectly.

**What I've tried**
What I've tried is to make 3 circles with position absolute and then use % (percentage) to determine the width of the colored parts, but I can't twist my mind around how it should be set up.

Any suggestions is appreciated,
Mike

Comment: You might have better luck with a JavaScript vector library like Raphaël: http://raphaeljs.com/polar-clock.html

Comment: Thank you for the fast response Blender. I'll look into the library and see if I can figure out how to use it.

Comment: @Blender - Your suggestions is a great alternative! I found many useful stuff on his website, absolutely a wonderful library, thank you for sharing. - If nobody else have a solution to achieve the circles as illustrated in the link provided above, then I'll use this JavaScript library you provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple try of me to achieve the effect you want:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/snGq6/3/)**

edit: [css-only solution](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/snGq6/5/)

It can be easily animated with javascript or keyframes. Arbitrary content would go into the `inner` div. To change the percentage, simply adjust the angle of the pseudo-elements.

With a little more effort this could be easily refined I guess;)

Note: the transform has the webkit-prefix, so it works only in chrome/safari - to see it in firefox or other browsers, you need to change the prefix.

P.S. I will animate it when I'm home from work.

Comment: Extraordinary! This is exactly the setup I was looking for! I thank you very much for the solution.

Comment: @Mike you are welcome. I wanted to try this out a while ago, so now this was a good opportunity to start;)

Comment: Maybe both of us will learn something new then :). Though, I'm slightly confused. I've never seen or worked with the way you define your CSS, as $br:60px; $dimbg=120px;$dimin=90px;$ etc., are they supposed to be listed inside the CSS?

Comment: @Mike it is written in [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). Have a look at it, it makes writing CSS very comfortable.

Comment: @Mike basically these are just variables. You can replace these in the CSS with their according values defined at the top and have valid css.

Answer (score -1):

Good one by **Christoph**   but he is using  SASS/SCSS which are comparatively slow then normal CSS because they have to be converted to CSS before browser render it so I have have a different Solution for you

try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gajjuthechamp/hAHju/)

Comment: I was reading about the SASS/SCSS, I installed Ruby and tried to "convert" the file to a CSS but, it's pretty confusing to be honest. I tried your approach @Champ and it was easy to integrate into my project as a static solution, I'm not a pro-css-dude but this was an easy approach. So thank you for providing this CSS-Example :) *brofist*

Comment: sry but you are talking nonsense champ - sass is precompiled, so it has absolutely NO impact on the renderingspeed of the browser. @Mike as i said you just have to substitute the variables, you could have told me and i would have given you a pure css-solution. I find it rather disreputable to give some other guy credit for the work I have done. Also this solution won't work as you would like to have it since it can only indicate 25% steps.

Comment: @ Christoph don't get hyper I am sorry about the comment that SASS/SCSS is slow and the work you have done its really admirable.but I have never taken credit for the work you have done the fiddle I presented is purely developed by me

Comment: @Christoph I apologize for making you feel disrespected. For the sake of you being the one introducing the solution, I have marked your reply as the "answer". Please bare in mind, I'm not very experienced with these techniques, therefor I just took the "easiest" solution, although I did went through to install Ruby and proceed with the solution you gave me, I was not able to be successful at it, therefor I took Champ's solution, although it's based on yours. I apologize for the unfair treatment.

Comment: Champ: Sure it was developed by yourself, thats why you have the exact same markup as my solution has... also how do you want to display lets say "67%"? You can only display 4 states and that is not what Mike wanted. @Mike i provided a css-solution for you. But perhaps you want to go deeper into SASS or if thats easier for you - [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). It is working with javascript and also can compile the css clientside. In every case it is a good thing to learn it - it will save you much work in the long run if you are working on bigger projects.

Comment: @Christoph Ok I agree that my solution wont work in Mike case but my source it http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-different-shapes-in-css not your markup